# ChartJS. Change axis line color

Tags: javascript, charts, colors

I wanna know if it's possible to change the color of the chart axis using ChartJS.

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I know this question was asked over 2 years ago and the OP has already marked a correct answer, **but** I have a solution to the problem that the OP mentioned in the comments of the marked answer and I'd like to solve it to save other people some time.

> But this changes the color of the axis and all the gridLines, what if
>   I just want to change the axis color? For example, I want the axis
>   line solid black and the grid lines grey.

If you're trying to achieve this, then the marked answer won't do it for you but the following should:

```
yAxes: [{
    gridLines: {
        zeroLineColor: '#ffcc33'
    }
}]
```

Comment: @Aceconhielo Aw nice one! Thank you so much. Happy holidays friend :)

Comment: From 3.x and newer versions, ChartJS removed `zeroLine*` possibilities. Use scriptable scale options instead. Source: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v3-migration.html

Answer (score 26):

you can change the color by scales configuration under chart options:

```
type: '...',
data: {...},
options: {
       scales: {
              xAxes: [{gridLines: { color: "#131c2b" }}],
              yAxes: [{gridLines: { color: "#131c2b" }}]
              }
    }
```

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks !

Comment: But this changes the color of the axis and all the gridLines, what if I just want to change the axis color? For example, I want the axis line solid black and the grid lines grey.

Answer (score 22):

Good question and good answer from @A Friend

His answer works perfectly well with ....... `chart.js` **v2.xx**

### Here now for version **3.xx** for those interested:

(as **v3.xx** is not backwards compatible with **v2.xx**)
Using `borderColor` instead of `zeroLineColor` to change the color of the chart axis using `Chart.js` **v3.xx**:

```js
  scales: {
    x: {  // <-- axis is not array anymore, unlike before in v2.x: '[{'
      grid: {
        color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)',
        borderColor: 'red'  // <-- this line is answer to initial question
      }
    },
    y: {  // <-- axis is not array anymore, unlike before in v2.x: '[{'
      grid: {
        color: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.1)',
        borderColor: 'green'  // <-- this line is answer to initial question
      }
    }
  }
```

Following a working snippet with complete code:

```js
const labels=["2021-08-01","2021-08-02","2021-08-03","2021-08-04","2021-08-05"];
const data_1=[39,41,42,43,43];
const data_2=[37,38,40,41,39];

const ctx=document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Data 1',
    borderColor: 'grey',
    data: data_1
  }, {
    label: 'Data 2',
    borderColor: 'grey',
    data: data_2
  }]
};

const options = {
  scales: {
    x: {
      grid: {
        color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)',
        borderColor: 'red'
      }
    },
    y: {
      grid: {
        color: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.1)',
        borderColor: 'green'
      }
    }
  }
};

const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<!-- gets you the latest version of Chart.js, now at v3.5.0 -->

<canvas width="320" height="240"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 8):

**In the Charjs.JS to style the scale label and ticks we can use below settings.**

```
options: {     
           scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'X axe name',
                                fontColor:'#000000',
                                fontSize:10
                            },
                            ticks: {
                               fontColor: "black",
                               fontSize: 14
                              }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Y axe name',
                                fontColor: '#000000',
                                fontSize:10
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                  fontColor: "black",
                                  fontSize: 14
                            }
                        }]
                 }
         }
```

Please refer the [link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#scale-title-configuration) for all the properties. Study all the property before implementation.

Happy coding !

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled upon this in 2023, looks like they have removed `gridLines`, `zeroLineColor` and `borderColor` in v4 (I am on ^4.3.3). Now, we have a separate border configuration in `options.scales[scaleId].border` as specified [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.3/axes/styling.html#border-configuration).

```
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          color: '#fff', // Color of the x-axis labels
        },
        grid: {
          color: '#ffffff44', // Color of the x-axis grid lines
        },
        border: {
          width: 2,
          color: '#fff', // <-------------- Color of the x-axis
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For ChartJs 3 updated in 2022
You can pass the `options` object when initializing the context. In the sample code I was use `x` to change the line color on X Axis, you can try `y` as well.

```js
options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          color: '#777777'
        }
      }
    },
```