# How can I change angular chart border?

Tags: angular

Here is my chart it have dark color:
[image]

I want to make background line white color and delete a small box next to my label Audio Feature. How can I do that?

Here is my html:

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
  <canvas class="chart-canvas" 
  baseChart 
  [datasets]="barChartData" 
  [labels]="barChartLabels"
  [options]="barChartOptions" 
  [plugins]="barChartPlugins" 
  [legend]="barChartLegend" 
  [chartType]="barChartType"
  [colors]="barChartColors">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

ang here is my components.ts:

```
  public barChartColors = [
    {
      backgroundColor: [
        "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
        "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
        "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
        "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
        "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
        "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
        "rgba(0,250,154,0.2)",
      ],
      borderColor: [
        "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
        "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
        "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
        "   rgba(0,250,154,1)",
      ],
      borderWidth: 2,
    },
  ];
```

[image]

Comment: Did you use any library to create these charts?

Comment: yes i install it from npm

Comment: Can you specify the name of the library?

Comment: Which library? that would be useful

Comment: Also `background line white` ? What do mean by that? Axis lines?

Comment: `npm install ng2-charts` and here's the link i got it from https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-chart-js-with-ng2-charts-e21c8262777f

Comment: yess Axis lines.

Comment: i just updated the image i want to look like

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958548/chartjs-change-axis-line-color